# Clustering based on model parameters

Tags: python, intercept, feature-clustering

I have been trying to clustering based on the SGD model parameters (Coefficient and Intercept). coef_ holds the weights w and intercept_ holds b.
How can those parameters be used with clustering (KMedoids) on a group of the learned model?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

So I want to make clustering based on `clf.coef_ (array([[19.47419669,  9.73709834]]))` and  `clf.intercept_ (array([-10.]))` for each learned model.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I think this question is a bit difficult to understand, what do you mean by clustering based on SGD model parameters?

Comment: i mean clustering based on SGD model parameters (coef_ and intercept_) instead of using X values (data points) @JohannesAck

Comment: Yes, but the coeff and intercept parameters are parameters of the learned model, not of the data points. 
Therefore it is just one set of parameters, clustering does not make a lot of sense here. Do you maybe want to use the SGD model to predict the potentially denoised Y value for each X, and then clustere these "denoised" (x,y) pairs?

Comment: @JohannesAck, I want to cluster the learned model based on their parameters (coeff and intercept parameters)? because this part is part of my big code for distributed machine learning

Comment: first, should I used both (coeff and intercept parameters) ? second how ? because they have different vector?

Comment: Let me see if understand your question correctly: you want to create multiple models (using SGD) and then cluster these models?

Comment: @ rotem tal, yes this what i want, using model parameters as input to KMedoids

Answer (score 0):

Build your X dataset for clustering by appending the coeffs and intercept arrays every time after you train a model, ie.:

```
X = np.vstack((X, np.hstack((clf.coeff_, clf.intercept_))))
```

Once you have all your data in X feed it a KMedoids model, ie.:

```
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

kmed = KMedoids(n_clusters=N).fit(X)
```

Note that you have specify N and you should probably test the clustering results for a number of values of N before choosing the best one based on one or more of [clustering metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).

Comment: I got the following error.....ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)     @mac13k

Comment: Check the shape and content of the input array.

Comment: @ mac13k         clf.coef_.shape, clf.intercept_.shape  return  ((1, 2), (1,))

Comment: You cannot feed those to KMedoids directly. Build the input array with 3 columns and as many rows as many models you train, then fit it into KMedoids.